# LINQ select date by differences

Tags: c#, linq, select, filter

I have an `IEnumerable<DateOnly>`, how can I filtering from that, or select from the IEnumerable collection those dates which day difference no more than 1 day.

There are some Dates eg. 05/20/2023, 03/31/1941, 02/02/1965, 03/30/1876, 02/01/1965, 05/21/2023, 12/10/1966, 12/10/1966

The expected result is (difference in days no more than 1)

```
05/20/2023, 05/21/2023,   
02/02/1965, 02/01/1965,  
12/10/1966, 12/10/1966
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if you have 05/20/2023, 05/21/2023, 05/22/2023, they belong into the same group even if the first and third have a difference of two days?

Comment: What did you try and where did you fail? You should at least put in some effort

Comment: Use the Property Date that truncates to start of the day at Midnight : MyList.Where(x => x.day.Date == DateTime.Parse("1/1/2023"))  Most DateTime objects contains hours minutes seconds and when you compare all you may need to any time in the day.

Comment: I able to implement it without LINQ I interested in with only LINQ.

Comment: Tim, you said correctly. I 100% agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for LINQ but that is not your best friend with queries like this, which depend on successors. You will mostl likely end with a query that is less readable and efficient than a simple (for-)loop solution. But you have asked for it, so here it is:

```
List<List<DateOnly>> result = dates
    .Select((d, ix) => (Date: d, Index: ix))
    .Select(x => dates
        .Where((d, ix) => x.Index > ix && Math.Abs(x.Date.DayNumber - d.DayNumber) <= 1)
        .Prepend(x.Date)
        .ToList())
    .Where(list => list.Count > 1) // all lists contain at least the single date
    .ToList();
```